# Problem with JavaScript not dynamically updating the options

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a simple frontend to help players create a tournament. But for some reason the options are not showing up in the second round.

Recreate problem:

- choose a map
- choose # of players
- choose teams
- click add another round

You'll see the option for # of players is not showing in round 2

Can anyone help me find the issue?

This is the codepen link - https://codepen.io/Nim-Chimpsky/pen/NWoOQxZ

Thanks.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Initialize the counter for the number of rounds.
    let roundCount = 1;
    const roundsContainer = document.querySelector('.rounds-container');
    // Select the first round element to use as a template for additional rounds.
    const firstRound = document.querySelector('.round');

    // Function to update the team options based on the selected number of players.
    function updateTeamsOptions(selectedPlayers, roundContainer) {
        // Define the possible team configurations.
        const teamSizes = {
            'Singles': 1,
            'Doubles': 2,
            'Triples': 3,
            'Quads': 4,
            'Fivers': 5,
            'Sixers': 6,
            'Crusades': 12
        };

        // Enable or disable team options based on the selected number of players.
        roundContainer.querySelectorAll('.team-option').forEach(option => {
            const teamSize = teamSizes[option.getAttribute('data-value')];
            if (selectedPlayers % teamSize === 0 && selectedPlayers / teamSize >= 2) {
                option.disabled = false;
            } else {
                option.disabled = true;
                option.classList.remove('selected');
            }
        });
    }

    // Function to update the player options based on the selected map.
    function updatePlayersOptions(mapValue, roundContainer) {
        // Initialize the HTML content for player options.
        let playerOptions = '';
        // Determine the maximum number of players based on the map selection.
        const maxPlayers = mapValue === 'Other' ? 24 : 12;

        // Generate buttons for selecting the number of players.
        for (let i = 2; i <= maxPlayers; i++) {
            playerOptions += `<button class="player-option" data-value="${i}">${i}</button>`;
        }

        // Update the players container with the generated buttons.
        const playersContainer = roundContainer.querySelector('#players');
        if (playersContainer) {
            playersContainer.innerHTML = playerOptions;
        }

        // Add click event listeners to the newly created player option buttons.
        roundContainer.querySelectorAll('.player-option').forEach(option => {
            option.addEventListener('click', function() {
                clearSelected(roundContainer.querySelectorAll('.player-option'));
                this.classList.add('selected');
                updateTeamsOptions(parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-value')), roundContainer);
            });
        });
    }

    // Function to clear the 'selected' class from a collection of buttons.
    function clearSelected(buttons) {
        buttons.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('selected'));
    }

    // Function to initialize event listeners for map and team option buttons.
    function initializeEventListeners(roundElement) {
        // Add click event listeners to map option buttons.
        roundElement.querySelectorAll('.map-option').forEach(option => {
            option.addEventListener('click', function() {
                const roundContainer = this.closest('.round');
                clearSelected(roundContainer.querySelectorAll('.map-option'));
                this.classList.add('selected');
                updatePlayersOptions(this.getAttribute('data-value'), roundContainer);
            });
        });

        // Add click event listeners to team option buttons.
        roundElement.querySelectorAll('.team-option').forEach(option => {
            option.addEventListener('click', function() {
                if (!this.disabled) {
                    const roundContainer = this.closest('.round');
                    clearSelected(roundContainer.querySelectorAll('.team-option'));
                    this.classList.add('selected');
                }
            });
        });
    }

    // Function to create and append a new round configuration.
    function createRound() {
        // Increment the round counter.
        roundCount++;
        // Clone the first round element to use as a template for the new round.
        const roundTemplate = firstRound.cloneNode(true);

        // Update the round number in the template.
        roundTemplate.querySelector('h2').textContent = `Round ${roundCount}`;
        // Update the ID of the players container to be unique.
        roundTemplate.querySelector('#players').id = `players${roundCount}`;
        // Reset the selection of buttons in the template.
        roundTemplate.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => {
            button.classList.remove('selected');
            if (button.classList.contains('team-option')) {
                button.disabled = true;
            }
        });

        // Reset map options and set 'Other' as the default selected map.
        const mapOptions = roundTemplate.querySelectorAll('.map-option');
        mapOptions.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('selected'));
        const defaultMapButton = roundTemplate.querySelector(`.map-option[data-value="Other"]`);
        if (defaultMapButton) {
            defaultMapButton.classList.add('selected');
            updatePlayersOptions('Other', roundTemplate);
        }

        // Create and add a delete button for the new round.
        const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
        deleteButton.textContent = `Delete Round ${roundCount}`;
        deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            // Remove the round element from the container when the delete button is clicked.
            roundsContainer.removeChild(this.parentElement);
            // Decrement the round counter.
            roundCount--;
        });
        roundTemplate.appendChild(deleteButton);

        // Initialize event listeners for the new round.
        initializeEventListeners(roundTemplate);

        // Append the new round to the rounds container.
        roundsContainer.appendChild(roundTemplate);
    }

    // Add a click event listener to the "Add Another Round" button.
    const addRoundButton = document.getElementById('addRound2');
    addRoundButton.addEventListener('click', createRound);

    // Initialize the first round with default settings and event listeners.
    initializeEventListeners(firstRound);
    updatePlayersOptions('Other', firstRound);
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px;
}

.left-side, .right-side {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 20px;
}

.rounds-container {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.options {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.options label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

button {
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.selected {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green background for selected buttons */
    color: white;
}

h2 {
    color: #333;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#addRound2 {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 1em;
}

#addRound2:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

.right-side label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#numWinners {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Game Rounds Configuration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> <!-- Link to your CSS file -->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left-side">
            <div class="rounds-container">
                <div class="round">
                    <h2>Round 1</h2>
                    <div class="options">
                        <label>Map:</label>
                        <button class="map-option" data-value="12D">12D</button>
                        <button class="map-option" data-value="LandRush">Land Rush</button>
                        <button class="map-option selected" data-value="Other">Other</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="options">
                        <label>Players:</label>
                        <div id="players"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="options">
                        <label>Teams:</label>
                        <button class="team-option" data-value="Singles">Singles</button>
                        <button class="team-option" data-value="Doubles">Doubles</button>
                        <button class="team-option" data-value="Triples">Triples</button>
                        <button class="team-option" data-value="Quads">Quads</button>
                        <button class="team-option" data-value="Fivers">Fivers</button>
                        <button class="team-option" data-value="Sixers">Sixers</button>
                        <button class="team-option" data-value="Crusades">Crusades</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button id="addRound2">Add Another Round</button>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side">
            <label>Number of Winners:</label>
            <div id="numWinners"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script> <!-- Link to your JavaScript file -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could this be the problem? `// Clear the players container in the template.`

Comment: BTW, IDs should be unique, you shouldn't have IDs in a template that you're cloning. Use classes instead.

Comment: Thank you! Not sure why I was blind to that. Thanks.

But this highlighted another issue I had earlier.

When I choose 12D in the first round (which limits the option to 12 players) I only get 12 players as an option in subsequent round, even if I choose "other" which should give me 24 players.

Do I submit a new question for that, or can I piggyback off of this one?

Comment: Better to ask a new question. And limit the code snippet to just the part related to the question, not the rest of the application.

Comment: Thanks, will do next time. For now, everything works :-)